# Netezza Stored Procedure Date Argument

Tags: sql, date, stored-procedures, dynamic, netezza

I really need someone saving me here. I get this error when running the below stored procedure: x and y are Date columns and z an integer one. I used to work around these errors. But this one is very persistent! I used all ways of adding comma around the dynamic variables or reformat the input date, but none works. It's static query works fine. Thanks for you help!

```
 exec SP_DIV_SKU_TIMEFRAME_SALES_V1( 14 ,'2015-02-04','2015-02-15')

 "ERROR [01000] NOTICE:  Error occurred while executing PL/pgSQL function SP_DIV_SKU_TIMEFRAME_SALES_V1

  ERROR [01000] NOTICE:  line 8 at execute statement

  ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  Inconsistent datatypes 'DATE' and 'INT4'"


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_DIV_SKU_TIMEFRAME_SALES_V1(INT,    date , date))
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE
item ALIAS FOR $1;;
date1 ALIAS FOR $2;
date2 ALIAS FOR $3;
sql varchar(30000) ;


BEGIN

sql:='

    create table DEVML_WORK..XxXX as 
     select x, y, z from k
     where x > '|| date1 ||' and y < '||date2||' and z < '||item||';' ;

RAISE NOTICE '%', sql;
Execute immediate sql;


END;
END_PROC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than the extra closing parenthesis on your CREATE line, the issue is that date1 and date2 are being built into the query as literals, but without quotation marks.

What you are getting is "where x > 2015-02-04" which is the same as "where x > 2009", when what you really want is "where x > '2015-02-04'".

Try the following modification, using the quote_literal helper function.

```
sql:='

    create table DEVML_WORK..XxXX as 
     select x, y, z from k
     where x > '|| quote_literal(date1) ||' and y < '|| quote_literal(date2) ||' and z < '||item||';' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer. However, I actually resolved the issue by adding two quotes like:

```
  where x > '''|| date1 ||''' and y < '''||date2||''' and z <   '||item||';'
```

The two inside quotes works out as one quote surronding the date variable and one quote for the statement!